# How to write a class which exposes only 20 of its Objects?

Tags: java, object, heap-memory

How to write a class which exposes only 20 of its Objects containing two methods `borrowObject` and `returnObject` .Code must be thread safe.Also write a method to get the number of Live `Objects`(`Objects` currently in use by other classes).

I can write the `borrowObject` method by using one counter.But how to write the `returnObject`. When client class call the method the Object will be destroyed.How to implement that.Overriding finalize method also does not guarantee that the Object will be no longer in the heap.

Comment: Please read -- http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: *When client class call the method the Object will be destroyed* I don't understand this. Have you tried it or maybe your implementation was broken? If you had problems with this, please post your code and we will gladly guide you to spot design errors and to upgrade your code.

Comment: You're probably looking for java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.  Read the javadoc and try writing some code.  If you still have problems, come back with a specific question.

Comment: 'Overriding finalize method also does not guarantee that the Object will be no longer in the heap.' You shouldn't ever need to rely on a quirk of garbage collection - once an object is not referenced from live code, it will get collected when Java needs to do so. Don't worry about it - unreferenced is as good as gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TwentyOnly{
    private static List<TwentyOnly> twenty= new ArrayList(20);

    private static int counter=0;
    private TwentyOnly(){
    }
    public static synchronized TwentyOnly  borrow(){
      if(counter<20){
        twenty.add(0,new TwentyOnly());
        counter++;
        return twenty.get(0);
      }
      throw new RUntimeException("All Allowed instances allowed");
    }

    public static synchronized void returnObject(TwentyOnly t){
         twenty.remove(t);
         counter--;
    }
}
```

Are you looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayBlockingQueue in the background pre-populated with a size of 20 members, and take from the queue when borrow is called, and push when return is called, and the active count is 20 minus the queue size ...

Answer (score 0):

You'd need static class member as counter of instances. Also the 20 instances are kept in an Array. Keep constructor private. Then implement factory method for creating instances which will control the counter member and place new instances in the array. Implement a method for disponsing of the objects, and updating counter and array refernces.